# Limit of functions of bounded variations.

Tags: real-analysis

$\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions of bounded variation on $[a ,b]$.

> Prove that $\lim\{f_n\}$ need not be of bounded variation on $[a, b]$

I am not able to get a counter example for this.
Can someone help me please !

Comment: Let $f_n(x) = n$

Comment: Thank you for the simplest example. Constant functions are of bounded variation on a finite interval but the limit function is unbounded and hence not of bounded variation.

Comment: @TheHolyJoker ! Of course the limit does not exist in your example. But in case I want the limit to exist but not of bounded variation, I should go for the example given by Mindlack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $[a,b]=[0,1]$. Let $f(x) = x\sin{\frac{1}{x}}$ (with $f(0)=0$). Let $f_n(x) = f(x)e^{-1/(nx)}$. Then it is easy to see that $f_n$ is $C^1$ on $[0,1]$, hence Lipschitz-continuous, hence has bounded variation.

On the other hand, let $x_n = \frac{2}{(4n+1)\pi}$, $y_n = \frac{2}{(4n-1)\pi}$. Then $x_n$, $y_n$ decrease with to $0$ with $y_{n+1} < x_n < y_n$, and $f(x_n)-f(y_n) = x_n+y_n \geq \frac{1}{n\pi}$, so that $\sum_n{|f(y_n)-f(x_n)|} = \infty$ and thus $f$ hasn't bounded variation.

Comment: That fn are continuously differentiable is not clear to me. Can you please elaborate on that point.

Comment: The functions clearly are $C^1$ on $(0,1]$. You can check by hand that the derivative goes to $0$ at $0$ (that’s because $e^{-\alpha/t}=o(t^n)$ as $t \rightarrow 0$ for any $n \geq 0$) hence the $C^1$ property.