# Do functions of Bounded Variation form a dense set?

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, bounded-variation

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3514769/limit-of-functions-of-bounded-variations) shows that the limit of a real valued function of bounded variation (BV) on $[a,b] $ need not have BV. This made me wonder if the space of functions $f \in BV(\Omega)$ (which is a subset of $L^1(\Omega))$ is not only open, but if it is dense. I've had trouble proving or disproving this on my own.

TLDR: **Is $BV(\Omega)$ dense in $L^1(\Omega)$?**

Comment: This follows from the fact that simple functions of the form $\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\mathbf{1}_{I_j}$, where $I_j$ are intervals, are dense in $L^1$, and that such functions have bounded variation.